# make own views on full calendar

Tags: jquery, view, fullcalendar

I would like to make my own views on full calendar jquery script. I see those examples: [1] [2] but I cant see where and how is creating the HTML for the view. I search on google, oficial documentation, discussion list but I dont get the answer.

Someone can say me which are more or less the steps to have my own view on full calendar? I would like to have an horizantal list of the week.

[1]  http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar/demos/resourceView.html

[2] http://www.paulthedutchman.nl/calendar_standalone/

Thanks for all! Regards.

Comment: Can you clarify your question - are you asking about re-styling the existing full calendar plugin or writing your own?  Have you tried anything out that you're having trouble with and can post code for?

Comment: I'm asking about re-styling with CSS and HTML to create new views.I read the full calendar plugin to know how can I create a new view but I dont find where is creating the HTML for custom views,

Comment: Where can one download these calender i cant find any link for download on their website.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the extended FullCalendar code that also contains the Resource View:

[FullCalendar With Resource View](http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/)

If you download the code and see there are only 4 files that have minor tweaks.

```
src/_loader.js
src/defaults.js
src/common/DayEventRenderer.js
src/common/SelectionManager.js
```

All the major lifting for implementing resource view are in its own folder (src/resource/*).

By studying the above mentioned files you can get an idea how [IKE LIN](http://www.ikelin.com/) created resource view and how you can create your own view.

I hope this helps.

BTW it's not a simple task. I hope you understand before you start. Good Luck!! :)

Comment: By **ABOVE MENTIONED FILES** I meant the files in src/resource/* directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot create a new view by modifying HTML. You will need to have some javascript skills to ensure your view works ok with Fullcalendar.
Check out my fork from fullcalendar, nextWeeksView is probably the one you're looking for:
http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews